# What's the difference between Polymorph and Spec?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

Recently a Spec documentation was [released on-line](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/70/80/67/PDF/SpecTechReport.pdf), how it is related with the Polymorph project?
It would be nice to read about the future of these projects. Is Polymorph discontinued?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polymorph is a UI framework. Spec is a UI *description* framework based on literal arrays.

In other words the widgets you see on the screen come from Polymorph. A UI builder takes a Spec specification and builds those widgets: "here's a button of this size, and this is its name".

In Squeak, the same relationship exists between Morphic or MVC, and ToolBuilder.