# A couple questions -- in regard to beginning Pharo

Tags: pharo

Using 2.0
Getting starting, confortable with Smalltalk, so tool questions I have not found readily in image or 'by Example' book (outdated).

Looking for entry field (not ready-to-use dialog box).
Like:

(TextMorph new) contents: '(enter name here)'; openInWorld.
  "but this just opens text, would like to be editable"

Would like to construct [simple] canvas with say four fields e.g. entry, radio, dropdown, etc. examples available?

Anyone know where 'PreferencesBrowser' has been moved to (e.g. keyboard etc.).

Is there a 'Local senders of...' in regard to class browser selected method?

Comment: One question per question, please. You know this after three years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to construct a UI you could either use Polymorph or Spec.

For Polymorph examples try in a workspace:

```
UITheme exampleDialogs.
UITheme exampleBasicControls
```

For a Spec tutorial have a look at:

[Bahman Movaqar, Spec - Part I: The Basics](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/spec-part-1-basics).

The *Preferences Browser* is replaced by the much nicer *Settings Browser* which can be found in WorldMenu > System > Settings.

And you can display a method’s senders in Nautilus (the new standard system browser) when you right click on a method name in the method list via the context menu.

Comment: Thank you Martin -- I assume then I was heading down the wrong path in regard to the Morph hierarchy (CheckboxMorph, etc)? ComposableModels are preferred?

Comment: You could still use pure Morphic, but that would be more complicated. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11260953) for an explanation of the relationship between Polymorph and Spec.

Comment: If you build browsers you might also be interested in taking a look  at Glamour. There is a chapter on Glamour in [Deep Into Pharo](http://www.deepintopharo.com).

Comment: That makes sense (Poly & Spec). Thanks Martin. Will try to look at Glamour.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read a Spec tutorial: http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/spec-part-1-basics